# R hide column name

Tags: r

I have this piece of code from a matrix called `dat3`:

```
cat("\nTwo equal rows\n")
  print(dat3[a,], colnames=FALSE)
  print(dat3[b,], colnames=FALSE)
cat("choose one of them")
```

However the column name keeps on appearing, even though the `colnames=FALSE` appears.

It's an interactive window, so it's not possible just to write `dat3[a,]`

I'm not interested in deleting the column name altogether, since I'll be using them later on.

How do I remove the column name from getting printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `print.data.frame` or `print.matrix` have the `colnames` argument, so it doesn't matter if you pass it or not. One possible way to do this is to use `write.table`

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=2:4)
> df
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
> write.table(df, col.names = F)
"1" 1 2
"2" 2 3
"3" 3 4
> write.table(df, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
```

You can combine it with `format` to have more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks you... How do you remove the " "" " beside the rownames?

Comment: @DannyVain-Nielsen `quote=FALSE`. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
# Printing dataframe while controlling row names and column names

# Create example data frame, df

df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=2:4)

# Print data frame with both row names and column names

print(df)

# Print data frame without row names but with column names

print(row.names=FALSE,df)

# Print data frame with row names but without column names

unname(df)

# Print data frame without row names and without column names

print(row.names=FALSE,unname(df))
```